# How to access data stored in hbase from spark in R

Tags: r, apache-spark, hbase

I need to get data stored in hbase to analyse in R but I need to do it through Spark because the data does not fit in memory.
Does anybody know how to access data in hbase through Spark in R?

I've searched both the web and SO but no joy. I've found pages that explain how to access data in hbase from R but they don't do it through Spark. And all the pages I've seen explaining how to access data in R and Spark (with sparklyr) provide examples with the iris dataset :(

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

One option seems to be to install rhbase and get the data from hbase and save it to csv, first, then use sparkr to read the data from the csv file and proceed to analyse etc. [blogs.wandisco.com/2014/08/19/experiences-r-big-data/](http://blogs.wandisco.com/2014/08/19/experiences-r-big-data/)

Is there a better way? One that does not require saving the data to a csv file?